# Вопросы кеширования аудиоплеера на сайте

Tags: php, javascript

Доброе время суток братья-форумчане. ))

Такая вот проблемка, может кто сталкивался и знает, как решается: есть аудиоплеер на сайте, там флеш аудиопроигрыватель и в параметрах ссылка на аудиофайл. Через админку закачиваю под этим именем файла новый трек, но на сайте проигрывается кешированный старый вариант. Что делать? Не заставлять же пользователей чистить кеш своих браузеров? Менять название файла в плеере не очень хочется... В php коде страницы выставляю заголовки, но не помогает:

```
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); 
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE); 
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Как всегда, буду премного благодарен за ответ по теме.

Comment: сам спросил сам и отвечу))
плеер нормально работет и не причем.
да, согласен, ссылка в плеере должна при каждой загрузке быть уникальной, либо путем довешивания любого гет-параметра с произвольным(рандомным) значением, либо менять название файла(что делать не хотелось, но пришлось идти по этому пути).
а так в принципе 50 на 50 что закешируется файл, прием наиболее упрямым оказался даже не ие, а фф6.

Answer (score 1):

Такого не должно быть. Как варианты попробуйте:

1. Поменять аудиоплеер
2. Проверить путь
3. Добавлять к имени каждый раз рандомное значение